# Extracting state abbreviation from string with 5 and 9 digit zip code in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I'm trying to extract state abbreviations from a column of addresses in a dataframe that have varying formats. Example:

```
"123 Any St., Some City, IL 65234 United States"
"456 Any Other St That Town, CA 62626-1234 US"
```

I used this code that works for strings with 5-digit zip codes, but doesn't work for strings with 9-digit zip codes:

```
df$state <- str_extract(df$address, "\\b[A-Z]{2}(?=\\s+\\d{5}$)")
```

How do I change this so that it extracts states followed by both 5-digit and 9-digit zip codes?

Comment: Match the state abbreviation with the regular expression, `(?<=, )(?:AL|AK|AS|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|DE|DC|FM|FL|GA|GU|HI|ID|IL|IN|IA|KS|KY|LA|ME|MH|MD|MA|MI|MN|MS|MO|MT|NE|NV|NH|NJ|NM|NY|NC|ND|MP|OH|OK|OR|PW|PA|PR|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX|UT|VT|VI|VA|WA|WV|WI|WY)(?=\d{5}(?:-\d{4})? `. Note that the regex ends with a space.

Answer (score 3):

When I use your code for 5-digits zip codes on the exmaple strings it doesn't work and returns `NA`s.

If we delete the last `$` then it works for both 5-digit and 9-digit zip codes:

```r
teststr <- c("123 Any St., Some City, IL 65234 United States",
             "456 Any Other St That Town, CA 62626-1234 US")

stringr::str_extract(teststr, "\\b[A-Z]{2}(?=\\s+\\d{5})")
#> [1] "IL" "CA"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tidyr::extract` function which works particularly well when you're working with a tibble/dataframe. In your case, I am doing the following: putting the data into a dataframe/tibble named `df`, using `tidyr::extract` to pull information into two columns-`zipcode` and `state`.

The `tidyr::extract` function uses paranthesis to distinguish what information you want in which columns. So since I am extracting to two different columns, I have two sets of paranthesis here with regex expressions inside. The first regex expression is `\\d{5}|\\d{5}-\\d{4}` which is saying to match on exactly 5 digits OR five digits followed by a dash and then exactly 4 digits. The next regex expression is `.{1,}` which matches any character 1 to any amount of times. Before I get to these two expressions, I match on any character as many times as necessary until I get to the zipcode with `.{1,}`. I separate these two columns out with a `\\s` (whitespace).

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(zipcodes = c("123 Any St., Some City, IL 65234 United States",
"456 Any Other St That Town, CA 62626-1234 US"))

df %>% 
  tidyr::extract(zipcodes, into = c("zipcodes", "state"),
          ".{1,}(\\d{5}|\\d{5}-\\d{4})\\s(.{1,})")
```